# Count value is changed when tableview is scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

This is my `CellForRowAtIndexPath` code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{


static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PickAClassCell";

cell = (PickAClassCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}
cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;
[cell.PlusCount addTarget:self action:@selector(PlusButtonSelect :)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 return cell;
}

-(void)PlusButtonSelect :(UIButton *)sender
{
UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[sender.superview viewWithTag:1000];
    NSLog(@"%@",label1);


        int count = [label1.text intValue];

        count = count + 1;

    NSString *Strcount= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];



    label1.text=Strcount;
}
```

when i click the plus button count value is increased but my problem is when i scrolling the tableview added count value goes to zero (default position).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you wrote

```
int count = [label1.text intValue];

        count = count + 1;
```

Every time you scroll next cell is created and the count is initialised with the initial value of the button and not with the previous cell's button int value.

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: Use an array to save the updated count for every button and then set the label's text with the count in the array in cellForRowAtIndexpath method, also update the count in the array whenever the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

This delegate call each time when table view cell appear on screen. Try to set tag of count label with help of any variable or try to add it through pickAClassCell.

In your case
`cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;`
This line execute each time when you scroll table view cell.

Comment: so in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` what changes i need. can you explain more.

Comment: Use a NsMutableArray and display CountLabel text through value of NSMutableArray at sameIndex.

Comment: can u post code any code for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //userCountHolder is instance of NSMutableArray.
    userCountHolder  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0", nil];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PickAClassCell";

    cell = (PickAClassCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    cell.CountLabel.text = [userCountHolder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.PlusCount addTarget:self action:@selector(PlusButtonSelect :)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(void)PlusButtonSelect :(UIButton *)sender{

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    int count = [[userCountHolder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
    count++;
    [userCountHolder replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count]];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: this code is working for you?

Comment: I just wrote this for your understand. I didn't run this code.

Comment: ohh, i am using u r code app is crashing.

Comment: did you initialise userCountHolder array with same object count  as number of cells in your tableView. I am using 3 objects for example in viewDidLoad method. Both userCountHolder array count and number of cell must to be same.

Comment: ya i am taking both count will same. can u run the code in u r simulation check please.

Comment: this is urgent please , i tried lot but it is not working.

Comment: replace this line- cell.textLabel.text = [userCountHolder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: no, not working

Comment: it's working for me. Try to find error using breakpoint and consol log.

Comment: in my side crashing. can you sent me the app through zipfile please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if ([self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
{
    // set count values here 
    cell.countLabel.text = @"";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else
{
    //set the normal cells values
}
```

Here `self.selectedRows`  is an array where you have to store cellIndexPath values when user clicked plus or minus button.