# When I scroll table view it removed selected items - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to scroll table view.When I scroll table view selected cell get disselect
As shown in the image I select P on the first cell.

[image]

But when I scroll the table it get removed. I am using button and image to select one button at I time.I am using custom table view cel. My code is like this

In Custom Table View cell

```
-(IBAction)passbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    Passimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pass.png"];
    Failimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"FailGray.png"];
    WIPimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"WIPGray.png"];
    NotApplicableimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAGray.png"];
}
-(IBAction)failbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    Passimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"PassGray.png"];
    Failimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fail.png"];
    WIPimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"WIPGray.png"];
    NotApplicableimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAGray.png"];
}
-(IBAction)wipbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    Passimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"PassGray.png"];
    Failimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"FailGray.png"];
    WIPimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"WIP.png"];
    NotApplicableimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAGray.png"];
}
-(IBAction)nabtnClick:(id)sender
{
    Passimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"PassGray.png"];
    Failimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"FailGray.png"];
    WIPimage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"WIPGray.png"];
    NotApplicableimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NA.png"];
}
```

In viewcontroller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *STI=@"STI";
    AuditTableViewCell *cell = (AuditTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AuditTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    cell.audittitlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.auditdesclbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

My question is how to set it value even I scroll tableview.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where are you setting the selected state of the button?

Comment: you need to store selected values in array. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` manually select those button according to values available in array.

Comment: You have to maintain the selected row's `index` and its related info so use the same each time the delegate `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Comment: Learn [How table view works!](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview), you need to learn basic concepts for tableview as i have marked that you are frequently asking this kind of question which shows that you need to know basic work flow of tableview! It'll be helpful to you :)

Comment: can you try this way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206915/count-value-is-changed-when-tableview-is-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Your cells are being reused so you get messed data. What you need to do is besides `idarray` and `namearray` to have `selectedOption` array so you can populate your cell accordingly.

This array can have values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and regarding the value you can set appropriate button selected with above methods you listed ( you can call `-(IBAction)passbtnClick:(id)sender` ).

For instance :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AuditTableViewCell *cell = (AuditTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AuditTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.audittitlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.auditdesclbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.selectedButton = [selectedValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setupCell];
        return cell;
}
```

And then, in your cell:

```
-(void)setupCell {
    if(self.selectedButton == 1){
        [self passbtnClick:self];    
    }
    // repeat for other options, use 0 to have none selected
}
```

For saving selected state, use delegate from cell to viewController to set value `selectedButton` in `selectedValues`. For delegates, here is the useful link: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: What is selectedButton and selectedvalues hear?

Comment: selectedValues is an array of selected state for each cell, selectedButton is property in your cell which you use to select corresponding button

Comment: Any luck with changes?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array called cellSelectedArray[] to keep a count of selected cells.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  cellSelectedArray = [[NSMutableArrayalloc]init];
```

// also update and insert values in cellSelectedArray equal to number of rows in table.
   // just set every value in cellSelectedArray to be false.

```
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AuditTableViewCell *cell = (AuditTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AuditTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        if([cellSelectedArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] == true){
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}else{
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
        return cell;
}
```

//in select delegate of tableview , just update the array

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       [cellSelectedArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] == true;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       [cellSelectedArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] == false;

}
```